# How to remove SKU's from ALL products in Quick View - already remove from each product page

Tags: filters

I have added code and removed sku's from all product pages (not admin) and all went well.  However I realised that if I click on Quick View on any product - the sku's are still there.

Can you please advise how to remove these

Thanks

```
<?php

function sv_remove_product_page_skus($enabled) {
    if (!is_admin() && is_product()) {
        return false;
    }
    return $enabled;
}
add_filter('wc_product_sku_enabled', 'sv_remove_product_page_skus');
```

Comment: Please provide more details. For example, please post the code which you have added and give some more details.

Comment: Thanks - the code I added is     function sv_remove_product_page_skus( $enabled ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_product() ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'wc_product_sku_enabled', 'sv_remove_product_page_skus' );     and the SKu's are no longer visible on the product page. However if I click on QUICK VIEW - the SKU's are still there.

Comment: And what plugin is this?

Comment: I added the code in the child theme - not using a plugin Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer you need. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work. **A quick tip for getting great answers**: Many experts are busy people. Help them get to all the facts as soon as possible (without asking follow up questions) and you will get many more answers. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try. I've modified your existing code to check whether it's a product or not. Let me know if it works.

```
function sv_remove_product_page_skus( $enabled ) {
   global $post;
   if ( ! is_admin() && get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'product'  ) {
      return false; 
   } 
   return $enabled; 
} 
add_filter( 'wc_product_sku_enabled', 'sv_remove_product_page_skus' );
```

Comment: Thanks - sku's still visible in Quick View